# Manejo de excepciones de función fetch en Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch

### Antecedente

Deseo evaluar la disponibilidad de algunos recursos como imágenes y vídeos a través de peticiones fetch usando el verbo HEAD de la siguiente forma:

```
const sources = [
    'https://imagen1.jpg',
    'https://imagen2.jpg',
    'https://imagen3.jpg',
]

const checkAvailability = async (url) => {
    try {
        console.log(url)
        const res = await fetch(url, { method: 'HEAD', mode: 'no-cors' })

        // { Validar estado de respuesta }

        return true
    } catch (err) {
        return false
    }
}

const checkUrls = (urls) => {
    const promises = urls.map(async (url) => {
        return await checkAvailability(url)
    })
    return promises
}

const checkSources = async (sources) => {
    for await (available of checkUrls(sources)) {
        console.log(available)
    }
}

checkUrls(sources)
```

### Problemática

En caso tal de que el recurso no este disponible, obtendré una respuesta con un status 404, el cual no es bien manejado por mi bloque try catch, entiendo bien que fetch solo rechaza la petición interna que realiza en caso de un error de red, sin embargo no logro manejar correctamente la respuesta obtenida, esto debido a que muchos de los recursos se encuentran alojados en servidores que no tienen habilitado CORS, y por eso lo máximo que obtengo es una respuesta opaca.

Agradezco de antemano si alguien me pudiera ofrecer una solución.

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39297738/5587982) me parece interesante para tu caso. `fetch` falla únicamente cuando hay un error de red, en cambio, los errores como `404, 500` y otros, son considerados exitosos desde el punto de vista de `fetch. Se puede evaluar por tanto `status` con algo así: `if (response.status !== 200) {  //hacer que la promesa sea rechzada ` haciendo que la promesa sea rechazada. Puedes ver también [este hilo de github](https://gist.github.com/odewahn/5a5eeb23279eed6a80d7798fdb47fe91) con varias propuestas de manejadores de error completos.

Comment: es cierto lo que dices, la cuestión en que como solo puedo obtener una respuesta opaca, el valor status siempre sera 0

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con *respuesta opaca* ...¿?  ¿Si haces un `console.log(res);` no encuentras allí elementos que informen sobre el tipo de error que vino del servidor? ¿El código de servidor es responsabilidad tuya? De ser así, podrías también trabajar del lado del servidor, para determinar el tipo de respuesta y devolverlo a la petición que haces con `fetch`

Comment: es un tipo de respuesta que se obtiene de las peticiones tipo no-cors, existen otros tipos de respuestas como las indicadas [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type), sin embargo en este caso especifico la respuesta no me retorna nada en absoluto, por ello lo que deseo es poder manejar dichos errores y que ingrese por el bloque del catch, sin embargo no entiendo como hacerlo ya que parece que el error se ejecuta en un scope que no puedo manejar

Comment: Ok, leyendo el enlace, las respuestas del tipo `opaque` se deben a que estás usando el `mode: 'no-cors'`, por tanto, a no ser que cambies a `mode: 'cors'` o que no pongas nada (valor por defecto), no podrás obtener datos de la respuesta. [La especificación dice que las respuestas opacas no traen datos](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-filtered-response-opaque), son severamente restrictivas. Si estás obligado a usar `no-cors`, entonces no te quedará otra que trabajar el código del servidor, verificar lo que ocurre en él y devolver un contenido adecuado.

Comment: exacto, ese es el punto, como los recursos pueden ser de diversos orígenes, no me es posible manejar ese lado de la comunicación, lo que me causa curiosidad es que a pesar de que se genera una excepción, el código nunca se va por el catch, es como si en el ultimo nivel no ocurriera la excepción, sino que parece que sucede internamente y se muestra la excepción con un console.error, por eso mi código no es capaz de asimilar el error

Comment: No se puede ir por el `catch` por lo que te dije en mi primer comentario. Para `fetch` ese tipo de errores no lo son realmente. Una respuesta `404, 500` u otra **que no sea debida a un error de red**, es para `fetch` una solicitud *exitosa*, en el sentido de que **se envió algo al servidor y hubo una respuesta**, sea esta `200, 404, 500...`

Comment: estoy de acuerdo con ello, creo que tendré que usar un XMLHttpRequest para lograr el propósito que deseo, o hacer un fallback del fetch en caso de que el servidor no acepte CORS

Comment: Me parece que sí, aunque podrías probar con el `mode` por defecto que es `basic`. No sé, al menos puedes revisar lo que hay en la respuesta y determinar si la misma tiene la información que requieres para manejar adecuadamente los errores. Como quiera que sea, si usas `fetch`, los errores **no de red** deben ser manejados prácticamente a mano.

Comment: de esa forma me indica que no es posible hacer la petición debido a que no esta permitido el CORS, haré uso del viejo XMLHttpRequest, agradezco tu esfuerzo por ayudarme a encontrar la solución

Comment: No es que sea experto en el tema, pero ¿por qué no funcionaría con `basic` y sí con `no-cors`? ¿No es eso contradictorio? ¿Qué pasa si pruebas con el `mode: 'cors'`?

Comment: los modos basic y cors son muy similares, la diferencia es que cors limita las cabeceras que se pueden leer en la respuesta, la situacion del por que no me deja es por que ciertamente no tengo permisos para acceder al recurso desde un origen diferente al propio del mismo recurso, para que cors o basic me funcionen el servidor debe tener la cabecera Access-Control-Allow-Origin con un valor * o con el valor de mi origen en caso de que tenga varios separados por coma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tras una evaluación e investigación de la forma en que se estructura la seguridad del navegador para realizar peticiones a orígenes que no permiten su consulta desde orígenes distintos he concluido que no es posible obtener una respuesta valida haciendo uso de `fetch` o un `XMLHttpRequest` no por el funcionamiento de ellos, sino mas bien por el sistema de seguridad de los navegadores web en si.

Dejo este [link](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#top_of_page) de la web de desarrolladores de Google para cualquiera que desee investigar un poco frente al tema.